# Vuejs data() value types with autocomplete in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I'm trying to get types to propagate from the data() state through to the rest of the component as I find autocomplete nearly essential for how I code.

I have a simple snapshot below, I return a 'map' variable of type L.Map (leafletjs if anyone is interested). However in the mounted() function, or any other, vscode/ts thinks it's an 'any'.

[image]

I have looked around to see if anyone has had the same issue and resolved it, but I didn't see anything.

Any help would be much appreciated as to where I've pooched it!

Comment: Have you considered using the composition API, it is easier to use TypeScript with that approach.

Comment: Thanks - 'Composition API' is basically use of reactive()? I've looked at some examples, such as [link](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/state-management-with-composition-api/). I haven't seen anything how to have a local state per component (I guess without creating a backing state file for **every** component)

Comment: not really, it is a whole new concept on how to build vue components with Vue3: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Tomas - you pointed me in the right direction for a work-around. I think I have half-followed the 'composition api' approach.

**Conclusion:** Short answer is autocomplete/type data doesn't seem to make it through from internal state in data()

**Fix:** I have mostly pushed my state into an external class that has a state dict, wrapped in reactive().

There are some cases where using this is a bit fiddly, but having proper type info is critical for me.